# How to convert text to data frame name in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset imputed by a R library mice. I am going to plot the column with imputed data with stripplot but with the data field specified in the program.

```
imp <- mice(nhanes, print=F)
pdf('result.pdf', onefile=TRUE)
f <- formula(parse(text="chl~.imp")) # it does not have to be chl, could be any available column
for (n in 1:4) {
  ap <- stripplot(imp, data=f, pch=20, cex=2)
  plot(ap)
}
dev.off()
```

To make it simple, I change the same column (chl) to be plotted 4 times. This case does not compile, it gives the error

Error in formula.default(parse(text = "chl~.imp")) (fott.R#59): invalid formula

If I replace the stripplot command with

```
ap <- stripplot(imp, chl~.imp, pch=20, cex=2)
```

it then plot the graph without any problem. I wonder if there is a way to refer the dataset name in stripplot with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
imp <- mice(nhanes, print=F)
pdf('result.pdf', onefile=TRUE)
n <- names(imp$imp)
for (i in n) {
  ap <- stripplot(imp, as.formula(paste0(i, " ~.imp")), pch=20, cex=2)
  plot(ap)
}
dev.off()
```